# Is there a faster way to extract lines from a file?

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I have a set of files that I need to search through and extract certain lines.  Right now, I'm using a `for` loop but this is proving costly in terms of time.  Is there a faster way than the below?

```
import re

for file in files:
        localfile = open(file, 'r')
        for line in localfile:
                if re.search("Common English Words", line):
                      words = line.split("|")[0]
                      # Append words to file words.txt
                      open("words.txt","a+").write(words + "\n")
```

Comment: For starters, stop unnecessarily re-opening `open("words.txt","a+")` inside the loop

Comment: You're using regex but your substring has no regex features. Why not use `"Common English Words" in line`? Anyway, this is rather broad. There are so many ways to improve speed. You could multithread it, for example. What might be best for your use case is unclear. What's fast enough for your needs? `open("words.txt","a+")` doesn't close the file handle, use `with` and move this outside of your loop. `open(file, 'r')` also leaks memory. `line.split("|")[0]` is a waste of memory -- making a possibly huge (?) list just to take the first element.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for the feedback.  Can I ask you to elaborate on your suggestion of `'Common English Words' in line?`

Comment: `"foo" in "foobar"` looks for substrings in a string. That's all you're doing here. Regex is powerful and takes time to build and execute, adding overhead. There's no need to bring out a machete if all you're doing is chopping a carrot. Use regex if you're doing something like `r"foo\b +(?!=bar)"` or actually using regex functionality in some way.

Comment: @ggorlen Makes sense, thanks.  Separately but related, Is there a 'vectorized' way to do this i.e. without using `for` loops?  One thought I had was to use pandas `read_csv` function which I believe allows for excluding lines based on pre-specified criteria.

Comment: I strongly recommend providing more details before I'm going to be able to make any further recommendations. The contents/sizes/count of the files, a description of the task you're attempting to accomplish, details of the environment you're running this in, a benchmark and profile of your current performance, an explanation of where the performance needs to be to meet your goals and why, etc. There are zillions of ways to speed this sort of thing up, and we could burn a lot of time on micro-optimizations that don't matter at all.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why you should always profile your code before you go trying to make it faster. Profiling the code will tell you which parts of your code are taking the most time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one thing, you are creating a new file descriptor every time that you write to the words.txt file.
I ran some tests and found that python garbage collection does in fact close open file descriptors when they become inaccessible (at least in my test case).
However, creating a file descriptor every time that you want to append to a file is going to be costly. For future reference, it is considered good practice to use with as blocks for opening files.

TLDR:
One improvement you could make is to open the file you are writing to just once.
Here is what that would look like:

```
import re

with open("words.txt","a+") as words_file:
    for file in files:
            localfile = open(file, 'r')
                for line in localfile:
                        if re.search("Common English Words", line):
                              words = line.split("|")[0]
                              # Append words to file words.txt
                              words_file.write(words + "\n")
```

Like I said, using with as statements when opening files is considered best practice. We can fully implement this best practice like so:

```
import re

with open("words.txt","a+") as words_file:
    for file in files:
            with open(file, 'r') as localfile:
                for line in localfile:
                        if re.search("Common English Words", line):
                              words = line.split("|")[0]
                              # Append words to file words.txt
                              words_file.write(words + "\n")
```

Comment: You're right. The overhead of constantly re-opening the output file is going to completely dominate the run time, far more than the use of regular expressions as discussed in the question comments.